# Can i make Radio Button's Text Editable?

Tags: android-studio, radio-button

I want to  edit the text of Radio button after the application run in the device successfully. Can i achieve this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="call" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="email" />
</RadioGroup>
```

So initially My radio Button is named call and email.So when i run this i need it to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

use this
 - RadioButton  rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMyAvatars);

- rb.setText("dfjhdfssdf");